# Can I reuse ECore models by importing them into other models?

Tags: java, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have multiple Ecore files for different purposes. I am now developing a tool which uses multiple models.

Can I develop an ECore model which references other models? For example when I have A.Ecore and B.Ecore, how can I create a C.Ecore, in which I have attributes with types from A.Ecore or B.Ecore?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To reference one Ecore model from another:

1. Open the model needing the added reference in the Ecore model editor.  In your example, open the file `C.ecore`.
2. Right click on the top item in the editor.  In the below example, you would click on the 
   `platform:/resource.../webpage.ecore` item.[image: Sample Ecore model]
3. Select "Load Resource", then browse the workspace to find the Ecore file you want to include.  In  your example, open the file `A.ecore` or `B.ecore`.

Comment: Thanks, this would help others too, certainly a better explanation then mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Loading a resource in the ECore editor lets you import other models. Once loaded, the types from other model can be used in the first model.